# Keep one zero and remove rest from the beginning if there are multiple leading 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I keep one zero and remove rest from the beginning if there are more than one leading zero.

The below regex if removing all the zeroes and not keeping the last 0

```
df.withColumn("strip_code", regexp_replace($"codes", "^0*(?!0[1-9]+)([0-9]*)", "$1"))

+----------+----------+
|     codes|strip_code|
+----------+----------+
|    541100|    541100|
|     54110|     54110|
|     05810|      5810|
|    581200|    581200|
|     58140|     58140|
|     54110|     54110|
|     48140|     48140|
|    481400|    481400|
|    723000|    723000|
|     52000|     52000|
|1234AZSHND|1234AZSHND|
|          |          |
|    001234|      1234|
|    034567|     34567|
|     00742|       742|
|     00763|       763|
|     00780|       780|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doing the following should work for you

```
df.withColumn("strip_code", regexp_replace($"codes", "[0]*(0\\d+)", "$1"))
```